# generating Unique transaction code/reference in java

Tags: java, spring, payment, uniqueidentifier

want to generate unique transaction code/reference like "2016100000223433" in java.

Requirements,

1. human readable(not too long)
2. use time,year, date
3. use primary key in database table(optional)
4. unique

Is there any method in java which can use ?

After getting others ideas created this mechanism. Is this suitable for this problem?

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.TimeZone;
import java.util.Random;

public class Transaction {

public static void main(String args[]) {

            DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            Date date  = new Date();
            try {
              Thread.sleep(1);                 
            } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }


            Calendar requestCal = Calendar.getInstance();
            requestCal.setTime(date);

            String newOne = requestCal.getWeekYear() + "" + String.format("%15s", requestCal.getTimeInMillis()+"").replace(' ', '0');

            System.out.println(newOne);                

    }
}
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html ?

Comment: Just write your own method. Concatenate all those values, then shorten it by using base64 or anything of the likes.

Comment: UUID is not human readable...

Comment: Unique and human-readable are harder than you might think to combine. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_1_.28date-time_.26_MAC_address.29

Comment: yyyyMMddHHmmss + primary key will always be unique, as long as primary key is unique itself

Comment: its need to be fixed length also. so cannot use primary key directly.

Comment: yyyyMMddHHmmss + hash(primary key).
not guaranteed unique, but unique enough for not having duplicate within a sec

Comment: If you need fixed length, consider left-padding the primary key with `0`s for example.